# Django graphene - mutation input without typing

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

In mutation, I just need to save the event name and its payload that might differ and I do not need any validation for it. How can I say graphene that I just need to accept an object?

```
class SendEvent(MutationMixin, relay.ClientIDMutation):
    class Input:
        event = graphene.String(required=True)
        payload = # any object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you can use the **`GenericScalar(...)`**

```
from graphene.types.generic import GenericScalar


class SendEvent(MutationMixin, relay.ClientIDMutation):
    class Input:
        event = graphene.String(required=True)
        payload = GenericScalar(required=True)
```